# Laravel - bestmomo filemanager

Tags: php, laravel

Welcome ! I have a problem. I integrated bestmomo filemanager with CKEditor and when i try to access it i have error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Code is :

```
  <textarea name="editor"></textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
                filebrowserBrowseUrl: '{!! url('/public/filemanager/index.html') !!}'
            });
        </script>
```

Thank You for help, Regards

Comment: CKEditor works but when i try to browse some files it give me above error about not found http exception

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your environment properly, then you should remove `public` from your URL as it's already considered the root of your application.

```
{{ url('filemanager/index.html') }}
```

Or

```
filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/filemanager/index.html'
```

On the other hand, you might also want to check that you can browse directories in your application.